# Laravel count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Tags: laravel, wamp, database-migration

In wamp I am migrating laravel project. when i run this command in composer-

```
php artisan migrate --seed
```

It shows this error:

> In Builder.php line 936: count(): Parameter must be an array or an
>   object that implements Countable

http://prntscr.com/j47gzs

This is php 7.2 error but I am using php 7.1 version but still getting count error.

Please help fixing it.

Comment: show some of your seeds code.

Answer (score 2):

With minimal code, I'm going to spitball.  Problem is most (almost definitely) likely in your seeds.  Somewhere you are using the count() function/ method incorrectly - for good reason, you've got a few options to mix up.

**In PHP:**

Say we have an array:

```
$array = array('One', 'Two')
```

Now we want to find the number of items in it using the `count()` function:

```
$length = count($array) // $length = 2
```

You can also use `sizeof()` which is simply an alias of `count()`

```
$length = sizeof($array) // $length = 2
```

**In Laravel:**

Laravel Collection objects have a method `count()` which basically counts the number of fillable entries in the collection.  This is necessary because even an 'empty' collection may not necessarily result in an empty collection object.

If you are dealing with a collection object `$collection`:

```
$length = $collection->count() // $length = 2
```

The big takeaway here is that if you are using Eloquent queries to seed, or are using the collect() helper on an array, then go the Laravel route.  Otherwise, just us the native PHP functions.

Hope this helped!

Comment: I can not change code. it is used in many placed in laravel files. Do you have any other solution?

Comment: How is it that you would expect to fix the error if you cannot change the code?

Comment: its used in a number of places and i can not change everywhere.

Comment: There really isn't a straight forward way to solve this problem without being able edit your erroneous code.  I'd suggest contacting someone who can modify it and ask them to investigate if my recommendations may in fact solve the problem.  Sorry I wasn't able to help further!

Answer (score 0):

It's very long time ago and I have the same error for now. So I try to check my model and change

```
protected $fillable = 'name';
```

become

```
protected $fillable = ['name'];
```

and it's work. Thanks ^^